# javascript hangman, issue when guessing word

Tags: javascript

1. Hi I am doing a project on hangman using purely javascript and am a beginner. I am looking to make a hangman game, currently I am having issues when I am guessing the word as when the user guesses an alphabet . It has to go in sequence, E.g word to guess is "cat" , the game currently makes it so that the user has to guess "c" as the first guess , then "a" as the second guess then "t" as the third.

I would like to make it so that the user can guess any of the alphabet without it being in sequence. The words come from a csv file

```
var readline = require("readline-sync");

class Word {
    constructor(word, definition){
        this.word = word
        this.definition = definition
    }
}

class WordCollection {
    constructor(pool, words){
        this.pool = [];
        this.readFile();
    }
    readFile() {
        const filePath = 'C:/FoP';
        const filename = filePath + '/input.csv';
        const fs = require('fs');



        try {
            const text =fs.readFileSync(filename, "UTF-8");

            const textByLine = text.split('\r\n');
            var wordline;

            for (var i = 0 ; (i < textByLine.length) ; i++) {
                wordline = textByLine[i].split(',');
                this.pool.push(new Word(wordline[0],wordline[1]));
            }
        } catch(err) {;
            console.log('file ' + " " + filename + " " + 'not found. Program terminated');
            process.exit();
        }        
    }
}
console.clear();

 
var numofwrong = 0;
var lettersremain;
var totallife = 9;
var lifelost = 0;
var answerArray=[];
var guess;


console.log("\n" + "-= Welcome to HangMan =-")
var namein = readline.question("\n" + "Please Enter Your Name :")

//Grab a random word from the array of words
var game = new WordCollection();
var wordrandom = game.pool[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.pool.length)];
var lastchosenword = wordrandom.word;
//console.log(wordrandom);

//Change letters into lowercase 
 var outputchosenword = wordrandom.word.toLowerCase();
 console.log(outputchosenword)
 
// Convert the word to " _ "
var outputunderlineword = new Array(outputchosenword.length);
var checkoutputunderline = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < outputunderlineword.length; i++) {
    outputunderlineword[i] = "_";
} console.log(outputunderlineword.join(" "))

//Display the Alphabets
var Alphabet = ['\nA', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
        'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','\nN', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
console.log(Alphabet.join(' '))


 
var correctans=[];
for (var i = 0; i < outputunderlineword.length; i++) {
    Enter = readline.question(namein + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ")
    if (Enter == outputchosenword[i] || Enter.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
        console.log("Good Job! " + Enter + " is one of the letters")
        correctans.push(Enter)
        console.log(correctans)
    } 
    else if (Enter !== outputchosenword[i] ) {
        console.log("Sorry. " + Enter + " is not a part of the word.")
    }
}
```

2. output when guessing for the letter (bat being the word to guess)

```
-= Welcome to HangMan =-

Please Enter Your Name :hi
bat
_ _ _

A B C D E F G H I J K L M
N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): b
Good Job! b is one of the letters
[ 'b' ]
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): t
Sorry. t is not a part of the word.
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): a
Sorry. a is not a part of the word.
```

3. output when the alphabet are in sequence

```
-= Welcome to HangMan =-

Please Enter Your Name :hi
bat
_ _ _

A B C D E F G H I J K L M
N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): b
Good Job! b is one of the letters
[ 'b' ]
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): a
Good Job! a is one of the letters
[ 'b', 'a' ]
hi's guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): t
Good Job! t is one of the letters        
[ 'b', 'a', 't' ]
```

4. Tried it this way but it shows an error

```
var correctans=[];
while (outputchosenword[i] !== Enter || (lifelost = 9)) {
    Enter = readline.question(namein + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ")
    if ((outputchosenword.includes(Enter) || Enter.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g))) { 
        console.log("Good Job! " + Enter + " is one of the letters")
        correctans.push(Enter)
        console.log(correctans)
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry. " + Enter + " is not a part of the word.")
    }
}
```

```
while (outputchosenword[i] !== Enter || (lifelost = 9)) {
                               ^

ReferenceError: Enter is not defined
```

5. After attempting the advices :) This is as far as Have come , I am not sure what I should do after this. Kinda stuck :\

```
while (lifelost <= totallife && !isEntireWordFound) {
    function guessLetter(wordguess, enter){
   if(wordguess.includes(enter)){
      var regex = new RegExp(enter,"g");
      return wordguess.replace(regex,"");
   }
   return wordguess;
}

wordguess = guessLetter(wordguess,enter);
console.log("after guessing 'h' word = ",wordguess);

    var enter = readline.question(namein + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ")
    if (outputchosenword.includes(enter)) { 
        console.log("Good Job! " + enter + " is one of the letters");
        correctans.push(enter);
        console.log(correctans);
    } 
     
    else {
        console.log("Sorry. " + enter + " is not a part of the word.");
        lifelost++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looping over your array (which consists of `_` chars. Here should rather be the number of rounds you want to allow the user to guess the word. Inside the loop you check for each round if the letter at the position of the round matches the input. Here you can write: `if(outputchosenword.includes(Enter) || ...)`

Comment: Keep in mind this would only be a quick fix, but might not exactly be what you are intending to do.

Comment: I see Thanks a bunch !, currently it has lead to an issue where when guessing for a word. The word only allows for x number of guesses = to the length of the word E.g 'lion' (4 alphabets) so even when entering a wrong alphabet or correct alphabet it only allows for 4 tries to guess the word, i would like to make it to guess till all 4 alphabets are correctly guessed

Comment: I see. I think @Jamiec's answer is getting you on the right track, so I hope that is resolved by now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your call for the user to enter a letter is within the loop of the letters of the word, you need to separate this out. In pseudo code

```
while user has not correctly guessed word or run out of lives
   get user guess
   if users guess matches any letter in the word
        do something
   else
        do something else
```

Without being able to (easily) test this code, you probably want something like below

```
var correctans=[];
var lifelost = 0
var totalLife = 9;
var isEntireWordFound = false; // set this to true somewhere!!

while (lifelost <= totallife && !isEntireWordFound) {
    var enter = readline.question(namein + "'s guess (Enter 9 for lifelines or 0 to pass): ")
    if (outputchosenword.includes(enter)) { 
        console.log("Good Job! " + enter + " is one of the letters");
        correctans.push(enter);
        console.log(correctans);
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry. " + enter + " is not a part of the word.");
        lifelost++;
    }
}
```

This is of course missing the part where you see that they have correctly guessed the whole word, and your part about "pass" or "lifeline" - but should hopefully get you going in the right direction. Note how this code almost exactly matches the pseudo code above!!

Lets have a look at how you might determine if the user has guessed the word. Not as easy as it first seems due to duplicate letters - ie, you cant just count that the number of guessed letters is equal to the length of the word!

One simple way is to remove all occurrences of the guessed letter from the word, and when the length of that becomes zero, the whole word is guessed

```js
var word = "hello";

function guessLetter(word, chr){
   if(word.includes(chr)){
      var regex = new RegExp(chr,"g");
      return word.replace(regex,"");
   }
   return word;
}

word = guessLetter(word,"h");
console.log("after guessing 'h' word = ",word);
word = guessLetter(word,"l");
console.log("after guessing 'l' word = ",word);
word = guessLetter(word,"o");
console.log("after guessing 'o' word = ",word);
word = guessLetter(word,"e");
console.log("after guessing 'e' word = ",word);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the help !, May I ask how a readline element method would turn out ? I have updated my code above but am getting an error

Comment: @Nexus I'll try to update answer with better code which more closely matches your situation - but harder for me to test as I dont have a [mcve]

Comment: Sure no rush ! Thank you very much again !

Comment: yup this really helped ! Thank You so much

Comment: @Nexus made a few tweaks after you marked this as answer which you may havemissed

Comment: currently the loop doesnt stop when the word is solved , may I know how I can stop the loop when the word is solved ?

Comment: @Nexus were getting into "code writing service" territory here ;) But let me ask you... how do you think you might solve it? How do you want to deal with duplicate letters? Traditionally hangman only requires you to guess a letter once even if that letter appears in the word multiple times.

Comment: for that I would use an if statement I would presume, when the length of the word has been guessed

Comment: @Nexus see update. I'll leave it to you to put the pieces together.

Comment: Sorry if I was crossing the line there, do let me known again if I am crossing the line. I have updated the code above and that's as far as I could go with my knowledge